# How to get halfbrothers/sisters in SPARQL?

Tags: sql, sparql

I have this RDF dataset with a family that has the hasParent realtionship. To search for all brother and sisters pairs I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?name1 ?name2
WHERE {
    ?subject1 oranje:hasParent ?object .
    ?subject2 oranje:hasParent ?object .
    ?subject1 rdfs:label ?name1 .
    ?subject2 rdfs:label ?name2 .
    FILTER (?subject1 != ?subject2)
}
```

However, How do I get all the halfbrother/sisters pair? This means: brothers and sisters that have only one parent in common.

Edit: maybe important, the dataset also contains the marriedWith relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?name1 ?name2
WHERE {
   ?child1 oranje:hasParent ?parent , ?otherparent1 .
   ?child2 oranje:hasParent ?parent , ?otherparent2 .
   ?child1 rdfs:label ?name1 .
   ?child2 rdfs:label ?name2 .
   FILTER (?child1 != ?child2)
   FILTER (?otherparent1 != ?parent)
   FILTER (?otherparent2 != ?parent)
   FILTER (?otherparent1 != ?otherparent2)
}
```